# Implementation of DLRadioButton - iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using DLRadioButton library, but I do not know how to implement it. I did not create the radio buttons programatically, I just set the button to custom and chose DLRadioButton in storyboard. How to select one option only in multiple radio buttons? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Below are the steps to use DLRadioButton.

1. Add a bunch of buttons into the view in storyBoard as u did.
2. Change the class name for all the buttons to DLRadioButton using the identity inspector.
3. Choose any one button and make a IBOutlet for it.
4. Now select this button, go to the connectionInspector and connect the rest of the buttons(buttons that you want to group) to the connectionOutlet "otherButtons".

[image]

And you are done. :)

You can choose to make the same as a multi-select checkbox by setting `self.radioButton.isMultipleSelectionEnabled = true`

(By default radioButton.isMultipleSelectionEnabled is `false` i.e, by default the button and the group of buttons that you have attached in the otherButtons outletCollection will act as a radio Button (single select))

Comment: I was wondering how to use the "otherButtons" before this. It is ok now. Thank you. =)

Comment: you are Welcome.. I also had used this library recently so the details were fresh :) If this helped, please accept it as the answer :)

Comment: Hey, do you know how to give every DLRadioButton a tag number? I want to put some functions inside my IF ELSE statement. Below are my codes. But it cannot function.

Comment: - (void)calculation
{
    DLRadioButton *button = [[DLRadioButton alloc] init];
    double purchasePrice = [self.purchasePrice.text doubleValue];
    double priceLabel = [self.priceLabel.text doubleValue];
    
    self.firstBtn.tag = 0;
    self.secondBtn.tag = 1;

    if (button.tag == 0)
    {
        priceLabel = purchasePrice * 2;
        self.priceLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",priceLabel];
    }
    else if (button.tag == 1)
    {
        priceLabel = purchasePrice * 3;
        self.priceLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",priceLabel];
    }

Comment: You can set tags for your firstBtn and secondBtn buttons in the storyboard only.
Select your button -> go to attribute inspector and set the tag. Or set it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Ok. I set them in the storyboard already. But it cannot function.

Comment: Oh.. i understood. What you are doing is wrong. Please go through the documentation. DLRadioButton has a method "selected()" which returns you the selected button directly. 

get the selected button and then check for its tag and execute the logic a accordingly.

`[firstButton selected]'

Comment: also.. you do not need both first and second buttons as outlets. Make an outlet for firstButton only and link the secondButton, from the storyboard, to firstButton's otherButtons

Comment: Very Nice. I want a radio button tap for only once. When It is already tapped, It shouldn't tapped the same button again. As I set some logic on tapping a button. So when I tap any button more than once, it keep executing the same code written for that which I don't want. Is it possible @dRAGONAIR?